# Right Continuity of limit function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to show that the following function is right-continuous, however, I'm not really sure a good way to approach doing so by using the definition.  This comes from an Exercise in Stein's Real Analysis book.

Fix $u \in [0,1)$ choose $\epsilon$ sufficiently small so that $u + \epsilon \leq 1$, and define 
$$
f_{\epsilon}(x) = \begin{cases} 
1 &\text{if } 0 \leq x \leq u\\
\text{linear function} &\text{if } u \leq x \leq u + \epsilon\\
0 &\text{if } u + \epsilon \leq x \leq 1, 
\end{cases} 
$$
where the linear portion is chosen so that $f_{\epsilon}$ is continuous. If $\ell$ is a positive linear functional on $C([0,1])$ (in the sense that $\ell(f) \geq 0$ whenever $f \geq 0$), let 
$$
F(u) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \ell(f_{\epsilon}).
$$

This function $F$ is the function I wish to show is right-continuous. Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: I think you should use a well-known theorem of Riesz:  The functional $l$ is represented by a function $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ of bounded variation, where $l(f)=\int_0^1f\;dg.$  If $ l$   is positive then $g$ must be increasing. Now if $m<n$ and $m\to \infty$ does $\int_0^1(f_m-f_n)\;dg$ go to $0$?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Actually, the point of this function is to be used in a proof of certain case of the Riesz Representation theorem: Given a linear function $\ell$ on $C([0,1])$, show that there is a unique Borel measure $\mu$ such that $\ell(f) = \int_0^1 fd \mu$ for ever $f \in C([0,1])$.